# I cannot access the juju-gui even though I have installed it and it shows me service started

Tags: juju, maas

I cannot access the juju-gui even though I have installed it and it shows me service started. I have installed it on the same maas server. It shows me agent state: started.

The public address given is bjayg.maas

I have used the internal IP address which already has a route added

Answer (score 0):

Have you run `juju expose juju-gui` ? This assumes you called your Juju GUI instance the default of "juju-gui".